# Why does the MySQL CHAR datatype have no preceding length byte?

Tags: mysql, varchar

In MySQL documentation one can find that CHAR datatype has no preceding byte with string length.

In contrast VARCHAR datatype has 1 or 2 preceding bytes where string length is stored. Which is understandable. Database engine needs to know what is the string length in order to read it.

How does database engine know what is CHAR datatype length? What logic/algorithm is behind it?

Answer (score 5):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html says:

> The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255. When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the specified length.

So there is no need to annotate the value in each row, because it's always exactly the same as the length defined for the column. The length is stored once in the table metadata, no matter how many rows belong to that table.

Whereas VARCHAR is stored in a variable-length number of bytes on each row, up to the maximum defined for the column.

In C, they might have used null-terminated strings instead of a length prefix. But in SQL, null is a legitimate character to store in a string, so that would not have been a good string terminator.

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like there are 2 ways of accessing string values. #1 CHAR length is taken from system tables. #2 VARCHAR length is taken from datablock. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Internally, the query has a cached copy of table metadata. It doesn't have to query the system tables.

Comment: @BillKarwin - What happens with utf8mb4 -- a single _character_ may be anywhere from 1 to 4 _bytes_.  Does the table actually allocate a fixed 4N bytes?  Or does it really have a length byte(s) in front (as if VAR), then play games to pad with spaces to meed the semantics of `CHAR`?  Keep in mind that there are multiple engines and multiple row formats for each engine, so there could be a lot of _different_ answered for the OP's 'simple' question.

Comment: @RickJames, A CHAR(N) may occupy more than N bytes. It stores single-byte characters one byte per character, but it uses as many bytes as needed to store the multibyte characters. It can also stay within N bytes by sacrificing trailing spaces. See https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/innobase/row/row0mysql.cc#L495-L516

Comment: @BillKarwin - Thanks.  Phrased differently: The space consumed for `CHAR(N)` is max(N, A), where A is the minimum number of bytes needed to represent any actual multibyte chars.  Trailing spaces are used as padding if needed.  Presumably, when comparing or measuring the string, code pretends that the string is padded to N _characters_, even if they are not physically included in the storage.

Comment: Yes. IMO, it would have been simpler to just treat CHAR the same as VARCHAR and TEXT. There's no benefit to a fixed-length row in InnoDB, so there's no reason to store them differently.